# smoothness of stellar evolution curves

Tags: stellar-physics

Consider a star $S$ which is plotted on an HR diagram, as a function of time. Then the curve so formed determines its evolutionary path. As per the equations [HERE](http://www.iucaa.in/~dipankar/ph217/fullstar.pdf)

is it necessary for the evolutionary curve to be smooth and differentiable?

i.e: is the curve $L(T)$ formed by plotting the luminosity for various temperatures at various times, differentiable and smooth ?

What I am trying to assess is the stability of the star throughout its evolutionary period by studying the above mentioned curve on its HR diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Stars are dynamic. Luminosity changes rapidly with flares or other outbursts — even collisions. Such processes cause a star to change temporarily, then return to the "normal" evolutionary state. Temperature is only taken as an average over the surface.

So, the plot of an individual star on an H-R diagram would likely contain many little loops and excursions. It wouldn't be a single-valued function $L(T)$, and even if it were (in the absence of loops), then it might be differentiable and mathematically smooth, but it would be noisy.

An evolutionary curve is a statistical fit to a noisy dataset, not a physically realized ideal.